# How to get a key value pair out of an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, linq

[image: Attempt 2 result]

I have two tables in the db 
table one "DocumentFieldValues" that has 2 columns  FieldId and Value and 
table two "Field" that has primary key FieldId and FieldName

I know the FieldName beforehand and I want to make they a Key. there are about 100 key/value pairs that will be in this.

```
Attempt 1 

   var attempt1= db.DocumentFieldValues.Where(x => x.PolicyDocumentId == id).Include(x => x.Field ).ToList();
```

Attempt 2

```
        var documentFieldValues = this.db.DocumentFieldValues.Where(x => x.PolicyDocumentId == id).ToArray();

        var bindingStringAndValue = from documentFieldValue in documentFieldValues
                       join field in this.db.Fields on documentFieldValue.FieldId equals field.FieldId
                       select new {  field.BindingString,  documentFieldValue.Value } ;
```

I basically need to be able to do data.FieldName and retrieve the value on the front end using a jQuery ajax call to the back end just need to pass this data back in the correct format.

Any help is very much appreciated.

I just made this and this works but is it the best way to go about it ? 
I only got 4 months experience on the job and only 1-year self-taught none with backend code  so dont hate lol I feel like performance wise this is pretty bad

```
    IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in bindingStringAndValue)
        {
            dict.Add(item.BindingString, item.Value);
        }
```

Attempt 4 this is the best way I came across now thanks @Orel Eraki

`var dict = db.DocumentFieldValues
                .Where(dfv => dfv.PolicyDocumentId == id).Include(dfv => dfv.Field)
                .ToDictionary(dfv => dfv.Field.BindingString, dfv => dfv.Value);`

Comment: If you got up to 100 FieldNames on one table, that means the Database Design is plain wrong. Propably a unresolved N:M relationship. You should spend your time redesigning the database and supporting the old way via a View.

Comment: that table is specifically for the question names and another table is for the values associated to that question name. the user can create there own questions for a insurance form on another page not related to this and its fine.

Comment: Both of them should work, double check you put DocumentFieldValues.FieldId as a Foreign key (which reference Fields.FieldId). And if not do it and update your edmx model.

Comment: @Orel Eraki so yes the other two will grab correct data  but the first one it grabs a whole bunch more it creates an array of objects and each object then has an array of more objects in it that.  Attempt 2 grabs exactly what I need but I needed the value of bindingstring to become the key and the value of Value to being the value of the key that  was the binding string sort of confusing

Comment: @JoshRice, Ok so you want to map your values into a `Dictionary<string, string>`. I've posed an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually did a good job.

You can do the following if you want it map your values into a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
var dict = db.DocumentFieldValues
    .Where(dfv => dfv.PolicyDocumentId == id)
    .ToDictionary(dfv => dfv.Field.BindingString, dfv => dfv.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much I knew there was a better way to do that then a  foreach

Comment: No problem. But take into account that this way is just different in a manner it's more expressive, compact and less variables that goes around. But under the good they are the same, because you attempts produces IQueryable so just when you're actually iterating over it it yeilds the items you want. which is basically the same.